# Ionic - Google map showing grey areas while dragging

Tags: android, angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, drag

I'm building an hybrid app that have a Google map incorporated in it. All loads fine, but when I drag the map around it shows grey areas until I release the drag and it loads the rest of the map.

Is there any way to load the surrouding areas without waiting for the drag release, so that the user doesnt have to navigate to a grey area ?

I'm using Ionic and Angularjs for building the app.

In my controller.js I load the map

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), 
{
        center : latLng,
        zoom : 16,
        mapTypeControl : false,
        streetViewControl : false,
        zoomControl : false,
        mapTypeControl: false,

});
```

And then I show it in my map.html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

Idle:

[image]

While Dragging:

[image]

On Release it loads:

[image]

Comment: You can try implementing https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps so that it utilizes native processing power.

Comment: Ye that's what I did, and now the navigation is awesome! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hybrid app Works like Web browser inside App. Google map in ionic also looks like that .When you drag the map it will show that part same as Web browser display it. It depends on internet speed of your mobile and performance of your app.
    You can take a look of this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/improving-performance-of-google-maps/894/2 to make better performance,

Comment: @Cláudio Barreira accept that answer and close this question please